# Equality and identity of Queues

Tags: python, queue, identity, equality

Will two `queue.Queue` instances ever be *equal* or *identical*?

I have some code where `Queue` instances are created, appended to a `list` and later removed.

```
l = []

def example():
    q = Queue()
    l.append(q)
    thingy = q.get()    # wait on background worker thread to put something in queue
    # ... do something with thingy ...
    l.remove(q)
```

For (I think irrelevant) context, other threads in the wider program will be putting their own Queues into the list, and there is also a background worker thread which will be putting objects into the Queues it finds in the list.

I understand that `list.remove()` first checks for *identity* and then checks for *equality*.  Therefore I want to know if two `Queue` instances will ever be evaluated as equal or identical.

Comment: I don't think so. Every object is unique, isn't it?

Comment: That is easy to test: `Queue() == Queue()` is `False`, so no, they won't. Unless you override `Queue` to change its behaviour.

Comment: @psinaught Not *every* object is unique. For example `[] == []` is `True`.

Comment: @zvone Indeed, thank you. I guess my, perhaps irrational, fear is that there will be some obscure situation where two Queues somehow become equal or identical. I notice `__eq__` is not implemented in the cpython Queue class, which I guess means it always fall back on the object ID?

Comment: Yes, the base implementation for `__eq__` is checking for identity, i.e. two objects will be equal if they are actually references to the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two objects are equal (`==`) if one of their `__eq__` methods evaluate as `True`.

Two objects are identical (`is`) if they are in fact the same object at the same memory address.

If a class (or its parents) do not implement the `__eq__` method, then an equality comparison falls back to being an identity comparison.

[The `Queue` class does **not** implement `__eq__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/865c17fb28f8c3275fd94da6ee4ac51472ec874a/Lib/queue.py#L27) so two Queue object will only ever be *equal* if they are in fact *identical*.

This can be demonstrated by the fact that `Queue() == Queue()` is `False`.